# Is it possible to recover overwritten data in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to recover data in a table overwritten with `WRITE_TRUNCATE` in BigQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can recover data using [Table Decorators](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators) - in particular Snapshot Decorator

you should figure out `<time>` right before you did overwrite your table and than run below query with destination table of your choice

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable@<time>
```

Please note: this will cost you querying that table
Technically, you can avoid that cost by using COPY instead of Query. So yo can copy `YourTable@<time>`. Copying is free

```
bq cp YourTable@<time> <destination_table>
```

See more about [Copy an existing table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool#copytables)

> To follow up S.Mohsen sh comments:

Above approach will work if yo just simply overwrote table using `overwrite table` write preference. But if you actually deleted table and than created another table with same name - I don't think above approach will work  - you can experiment though!

Comment: it seems in the doc that this only works with deletion not when data is overwritten and table with the same name and different data exists; Am I right? is there a way to recover overwritten tables?

Comment: it works with overwritten table too. unless you mean something else by "overwritten data" - just try. It definitelly works for me

Comment: reading again your comment and looks like you have not just simply overwritten data, but most likely deleted original table and than created another table with the same name but different schema - if this is a case - i am not sure that snapshot approach will help. I think if you create table later - you will not be able to recover old table.

Comment: no i did overwrite the data and thanks, it worked for me. My first tries had failed because I was using a wrong time format

Comment: super. glad you get your data back :o)