# Recover overwritten Bigquery table with older table schema

Tags: google-bigquery

I accidentally overwrote an existing table by using it as a temporary table to store result of another select. Is there a way to roll it back if both the old table and new table has a different table structure? Is it possible to prevent someone from overwriting a particular table to prevent this in future?

There is a comment in following question which says it is not possible to recover if table schema is different. Not sure if that has changed recently.

[Is it possible to recover overwritten data in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41072579/is-it-possible-to-recover-overwritten-data-in-bigquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first overwrite your table again with something (anything) that has exact same schema as your "lost" table

Then follow same steps as in referenced post  - which is :

```
SELECT * FROM [yourproject:yourdataset.yourtable@<time>]
```

You can use @0 if your table was not changed for last week or so or since creation

Or, to avoid cost - do bq cp ....

Comment: So, If i understand this correctly, bq cp will recover the old table with data as long as the current structure matches the structure i am trying to recover. Problem is that I don't even know the old schema. Table was created from a script that doesn't exist any more. I am doing this only for testing our implementation with BigQuery right now. However, I am more concerned that someone may overwrite data just like I did. Is there a way to prevent schema modification for certain tables in a dataset by anyone but Admin?

Comment: yes - for the first part . and - yes - you must know schema. if that table was used - you might "reverse engineer" the schema by checking for old jobs that used that table

Answer (score 0):

You could restore in SQL. *But* this loses column nullable and description fields and incurs query costs

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE project:dataset.table AS SELECT * FROM project:dataset.table FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)"
```

I recently found this to be more effective

Get a unix time stamp in milliseconds and override itself with `cp`

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "SELECT DATE_DIFF(TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 100 MINUTE), TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01', MILLISECOND)"
bq cp project:dataset.table@1625288152215 project:dataset.table
```

Before you do it you can check with the following

```
bq show --schema --format=prettyjson project:dataset.table@1625288152215 > schema-a.json
bq show --schema --format=prettyjson project:dataset.table > schema-b.json
diff schema-a.json schema-b.json
```